# Correct Dagger2 Implementation with Retrofit and Callbacks

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm working on refactoring a project and I want to start with dependency injection and getting Dagger working throughout the project.  I have an example posted below for what i've done so far, and it works, but I want to see if its implemented correctly, and if there is a way to have optional fields in the BindsInstance for a component.

My example here follows the path of:

Fragment -> ServiceUtil -> Service

My Fragment creates an instance of a ServiceUtil class and sets one of the Callback properties to a function that exists in the fragment.  My ServiceUtil class then uses Retrofit and an instance of my Service interface to make the API call and return the callback.

Questions:

1. Does the way i've set this up below make sense and is it correct architecturally?
2. Should I have created two components, one between the Fragment and the ServiceImpl, and one between the ServiceImpl and the Service?
3. I have some ServiceImpl classes with multiple Callbacks because that ServiceImpl handles multiple defined services in the service class.  For example I have a Service for ForgotPassword that requires 3 APIs.  So I have 3 APIs defined in the ForgotPasswordService interface, and therefore three callbacks in its implementation class.  Is there a way I can have the call backs be optional in my component?  Some screens may only use 1 of the 3 api calls.

Fragment:

```
public class Fragment1 extends BaseFragment
{
    @Inject
    ForgotPasswordServiceImpl forgotPasswordServiceImpl;

    public static Fragment1 newInstance()
    {
        return new Fragment1();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        ComponentA daggerComponentA = DaggerComponentA.builder().apiCallback(apiCallback).baseUrl(Urls.basePreauthUrl).build();
        daggerComponentA.inject(this);

    }

    private Callback<String> apiCallback = new CustomCallback<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponseReceived(Call<String> call, Response<String> response)
        {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            if (statusCode == HttpCodes.OK && response.body() != null  && response.body().getStatus().equals(SUCCESS_INDICATOR) && !response.body().getParticipantID().isEmpty())
            {
                //Update some stuff
            }else{
                //Update some stuff
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSessionExpired(Call<String> call, Response<String> response)
        {
            //Do something different
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Throwable t)
        {
            //Do Something
        }
    };

}
```

ServiceImpl Class

```
public class MyServiceImpl
{

    MyServiceImpl myService;
    Callback<String> apiCallback;


    public MyServiceImpl(MyServiceImpl myService, Callback<String> apiCallback){
        this.myService = myService;
        this.apiCallback = apiCallback;
    }

    public void callApi(String test){

        Call<String> api = myService.findUser();
        api.enqueue(apiCallback);
    }
}
```

Service Class

```
public interface MyService
{
    @POST(Urls.exampleUrl)
    Call<String> findUser();
}
```

Component Class

```
@Component(modules = {TestModule.class})
public interface TestComponent
{
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance Builder baseUrl(@Named("baseUrl") String baseUrl);
        @BindsInstance Builder apiCallback(@Named("apiCallback") Callback<String> apiCallback);
        ForgotPasswordComponent build();
    }
    void inject(Fragment1 fragment1);
}
```

TestModule Class

```
@Module
public class TestModule extends PreAuthBaseModule
{
    @Provides
    public MyService myService(Retrofit retrofit){
        return retrofit.create(MyService.class);
    }

    @Provides
    public Callback<String> apiCallback(@Named("apiCallback") Callback<String> apiCallback){
        return apiCallback;
    }

    @Provides
    public MyServiceImpl myServiceImpl(MyService myService, Callback<String> apiCallback){
        return new MyServiceImpl(myService, apiCallback);
    }
}
```

PreAuthBaseModule Class

```
@Module(includes = {PreAuthOkHttpClientModule.class, JacksonConverterFactoryModule.class})
public class PreAuthBaseModule
{
    @Provides
    public Retrofit retrofit(@Named("baseUrl") String baseUrl, OkHttpClient okHttpClient, JacksonConverterFactory factory){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(factory)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
}
```